# Has_many Association in FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, factory-bot, has-many

I have 2 classes Users and Authentications, then Authentications has_many Users:

User class:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name   "Juan"
    last_name    "Iturralde"
    sequence(:email)  { |n| "person-#{n}@example.org" }
    password  "1234567890"
    password_confirmation "1234567890"
    is_admin false
    factory :admin do
        is_admin true
    end
    after(:create) do |user|
        create(:authentication, user: user)
    end
  end
end
```

Authentication class:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :authentication do
    user        {User.first || create(:user)}
    provider    "Apple"
    uid         "uid"
  end
end
```

And i dont now. How create an user in authentication?

Comment: please have a look into [associations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations) section in getting started guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build associations in specs I use the following:

```
# spec/factories/posts.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
    title 'The best post'

    trait :with_comments do
      create_list :comment, 3
    end
  end
end

# spec/factories/comments.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :comment do
    post
    content 'Really awesome post'
  end
end

# in specs
. . .
let(:post_with_commments) { create :post, :with_comments }
. . .
```